# Where are the Downloads stored on an LG Nexus 5x?

Tags: storage, nexus-5x

I'm trying to transfer the contacts from my old phone to my new Nexus 5X.  I exported the contacts to a .vcf file and used adb push to copy the file to the Nexus 5X in the /sdcard/Download/ directory.

Unfortunately, when I use the "Import from .vcf file" option in the contacts list and look at the Downloads section all I see is a PDF I downloaded from Lego.com.  This .pdf is not visible in /sdcard/Download, and I can not find that .pdf anywhere in the filesystem using `find / -name '*.pdf' -print 2> /dev/null` from an adb shell.

Where should I put the .vcf file so it is visible in the list of Downloads used by the contacts activity?

Comment: Are you not able to do this: go into your File manager -> Downloads -> tap once on the file and choose "Open With" -> "Contacts"?

Comment: Can you see the file if you open the left panel and chose 'Internal Storage' then open the 'Downloads' folder?

Comment: Firelord, that procedure appears to have accomplished my original mission, although it does not answer this question.

Comment: Okay, so can you try moving that file in the root of your sdcard and then try to import and see if Contacts app finds it?

Comment: Moving the .vcf file from /sdcard/Download/ into /sdcard/ does not make it visible to the Contacts' import activity.  I suspect that I would have to move it into the same (as-yet-unknown) directory as the .pdf file for it to appear on the list.